# Github permission issue from developer's perspective when working on someone else's Organisation

Tags: professionalism, security

I am working on a project where the company seems suspicious to me. It's a remote job. They invited me to their Organisation and I accepted it on my Github. They have Android, iOS & Backend developer team and I am the sole developer of iOS and what I want is a complete control over my code (Project). So that if they delete me in future without paying, I can restrict them to access my code. I haven't even created the project yet, so what would be the best approach to deal with it? Thanks!

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because how to use technical tools is off-topic for this site.

Comment: But even given my close vote - this is just not going to work. They've got the code, they don't care if they've got access to the git repo or not.

Comment: I asked this on "https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/421289/github-permission-issue-from-developers-perspective-when-working-on-someone-els?noredirect=1#comment592613_421289". Then a moderator gave me "https://workplace.stackexchange.com/" and suggested me to post here! @PhilipKendall

Comment: If you're not sure how github works with organizations (I don't know either), start a private project on gitlab or bitbucket and don't share your code until you're paid in full.

Comment: I am aware of that, but I was wondering if there's any scope available within the scenario. Thanks for the suggestion btw.

Comment: Scope? Are you looking for a technical solution? or are you looking for a solution that doesn't require you to ask for full payment before you share your code deliverables?

Comment: Also, depending on contract it may be illegal to remove their access to the code. The general concept is that you have to sue for damages, not take justice into your own hands.

Comment: @TomTom I know. But here's the thing, the contract they gave me doesn't seems legit. Because their company haven't even registered yet. So technically you can't sue them. But the project is easy and I want to do it. So I am here looking for options.

Comment: @StephanBranczyk I mean the solution where I shouldn't share my repo with them until they pay me & it will work. Thanks!

Comment: "But here's the thing, the contract they gave me doesn't seems legit." - Argue that in front of a judge if you received a downpayment. You are in for trouble - the contract IS valid.

Comment: It's github. Unless you never give them access to your code, assume they have a local copy. And if you never want to give them access before being paid, might as well not upload to github before then.

Comment: there's no technical way to "control your code".    it's inconceivable they'll let you work for them unless they see all your code all the time.   (sure, on multi-million dollars major corporate projects it may work like that, I'm sorry, it's inconceivable someone like you or me will get a deal like that!)

Comment: bro you seem to be saying "the company us suss and sucks".  If so: Just Walk Away.

Comment: In any case, you could try alike questions on https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/ It used to be programmers.SE, and [dubbed as](https://stackoverflow.blog/2010/09/29/good-subjective-bad-subjective/) the "subjective variant of stackoverflow".

Comment: Thanks for your reply everyone. I understand it. :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your contract is a legal document. You enforce it using the court system.

If you cannot trust the court system to enforce the contract (maybe the company is outside of your jurisdiction or has better lawyers or is a scam altogether) then you should not take it.

Keeping the source code until you get paid will not work. Why would a company do that? They run the same risk you do, if they sent the money and you don't deliver, what then?

So, only enter in contracts that you can trust to be enforced if need be. Not by you, but by the legal system. No github setting will protect you from fraud.

Comment: “Keeping the source code until you get paid will not work.” - Especially if a down payment was paid.  This type of action will result in a judge immediately ordering you to provide a copy of the application. You were contracted to write an application, if you attempt to the code hostage, you will inadvertently be blackmailing the company.  If you feel the contract isn’t “legitimate” do a contract modification or something walk away. It’s not **your** code it’s the companies

Comment: @nvoigt Thanks for your answer. `(maybe the company is outside of your jurisdiction or has better lawyers or is a scam altogether)` This is the exact case for me. That's why I was looking for a solution. Btw I am going to take the risk. Let's see.